# Issue while executing PhantomJS Cron Job

Tags: cron, phantomjs

I'm trying to execute a PhantomJS JavaScript file via cron job.

Desired Output:

I just want the file itself to run and execute the javascript code.

Here is what I've tried:

```
* * * * * http://example.com/file.js
```

I've also tried:

```
* * * * * wget http://example.com/file.js
```

this doesn't seem to be doing anything. Am I missing some action verbs before the url path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing some action verbs before the url path?

Of course — you're either trying to run a script file (which is not a program to be run *), or you're trying to download a script, which will do just that, only download the file.

The script doesn't run by itself, it must executed by a program therefore you should first run a program and then give it the path to your script as an argument:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/phantomjs /path/to/script.js
```

________

* However by using [interpreter directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_directive) you could make a script runnable. Let's assume that phantomjs is located at `/usr/bin/phantomjs`. Then if at the beginning of the script you add

```
#!/usr/bin/phantomjs
```

And then make script executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.js
```

Then you could just run the script from commandline (or cron directive) by itself:

```
/path/to/script.js
```